# shell script output required in a single mail

Tags: shell, csv

Currently I have a shell script generating output in 2 emails with 2 output files (extract-rpt.csv, dump-rpt.csv) for 2 sql queries

unix2dos $REPORT_HOME/extract-rpt.xls | uuencode extract-rpt.csv | mailx -s "Extract" ${EMAIL_LIST}

unix2dos $REPORT_HOME/dump-rpt.xls | uuencode dump-rpt.csv | mailx -s "Dump" ${EMAIL_LIST}

My requirement is

1. shell script to generate this output in 1 email with 1 output file (process.csv) having 2 tabs (extract-rpt.csv, dump-rpt.csv)
2. shell script to generate this output in 1 email with 2 output files (extract-rpt.csv, dump-rpt.csv)

Comment: Could you provide an example or clarification what you intend to do?

Answer (score 0):

You can't do #1; CSV files do not define Excel tabs.  I think that's what you're asking for.

For #2, you need to attach the files rather than putting them in the body of the email.  Look at the "-a" option to mailx if you're using a new enough version of mailx, or you'll have to use a different mail creation program that can create attachments - for example, you can pipe messages into mutt, or there are libraries for sending mail from most scripting languages.

Comment: for #1; If the output file is Excel file and not csv file can we send the output in single file with 2 tabs. #2; Currently in the received 2 output emails I have the output files as attachment. Could you please send me the code using -a option that you are referring to generate this output in 1 email with 2 output files

Answer (score 0):

Found solution for requirement #2 to attach files when sending E-Mail messages from the Unix mailx utility:

http://www.orafaq.com/scripts/unix/mailx.txt

Thanks everyone!